# Non-spray WD-40 equivalent?

Tags: moisture, corrosion, lubrication, rust-proofing

I spray WD-40 on metal parts in a high moisture area to prevent rust.  But in one particular case, I don't want the oil getting on other things in a tight area, so I'm reluctant to use the spray.  Is there like a non-spray equivalent of WD-40 that I could smear on by hand or coat with a paint brush to the thing I want to protect from rust?  It should ideally protect against rust for several years without requiring any more applications.

Comment: You can purchase wd40 in gallon cans

Comment: Someone actually using WD-40 for what it's designed for?  I was about to jump in with "WD-40 is rubbish for that, you really want <X>" which applies in almost all cases...  but protecting metal by displacing water is actually what WD-40 is for.  Do keep it off plastics unless you want them damaged.

Comment: Although now that I said that, I think what you really want is Rustoleum 7769 Rusty Metal Primer. Only have to apply it once instead of weekly, and it applies with a throwaway bristle brush.

Comment: `coat with a paint brush to the thing I want to protect`  ... what is preventing you from spraying WD-40 on the brush?

Answer (score 4):

Spray onto a cloth or rag and wipe on.

Avoids any overspray if you prepare the cloth/rag away from that area.

Comment: wouldn't the rag absorb most of it though?  Is there a particular type of rag that would work best for this?  I guess I could put on some disposable latex gloves, spray on the gloves, and then wipe on

Answer (score 2):

You can buy WD-40 in gallon cans that are not aerosol spray. These are meant to refill manual pump spray bottles, but you can use it in the way you proposed of course.

[image]

But if you want it to stick around for longer, it might be better to use something like actual grease or even paint. WD-40 is pretty thing, and does evaporate.

Comment: only problem is a gallon is way too much!

Answer (score 1):

[Cosmoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmoline). Or grease, but cosmoline is (now) formulated specifically for rust prevention.

Petroleum jelly or Vapo-rub are moderately effective and perhaps easier to clean off, not to mention being available at any drug store or grocery store.